# Dúvida lógica de programação C

Tags: c, lógica, tipagem, divisão

Estou aprendendo a programar em C usando o livro Linguagem C - Completa e descomplicada do André Backes. Tem um exercício que não consigo obter a resposta corretamente. Segue o Enunciado:

> (O exercício foi levemente alterado) Faça um programa que leia o salário de um trabalhador e o valor de empréstimo pedido.
>   Se o valor do empréstimo:
>
> - For **20 % maior que o valor do salário**, imprima: “Empréstimo não concedido.”
> - **Caso contrário**, imprima: “Empréstimo concedido.”

segue abaixo o meu código

```
int n1; // salário
int n2; // valor empréstimo
int resultado;
scanf ("%d %d",&n1,&n2);

resultado = n2/n1;
if (resultado <= 1.2){
    printf("emprestimo concedido");
}else{
    printf("emprestimo nao concedido");
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem como fazer isto certo de forma simples para um iniciante. E é uma pena que um livro ensine desta forma.

Mas para fazer funcionar mais ou menos (tem problemas de arredondamento) pode usar um tipo `float`. O `int` não pode ser usado porque valores monetário não são só inteiros, tem parte decimal para os centavos. Mesmo que fossem ainda assim geraria um decimal depois de fazer a divisão e é pouco provável que deseje descartar a parte decimal gerada.

Só para entender a lógica ok, mas não faça isto com valor monetário real.

Aproveitei e simplifiquei o código que tinha muita coisa sem necessidade. Além disto coloquei bons nomes para as variáveis, assim não precisa colocar comentário.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float salario;
    float emprestimo;
    scanf ("%f %f", &salario, &emprestimo);
    printf("emprestimo%s concedido", emprestimo /salario <= 1.2 ? "" : " nao");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Cv6wCP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/odjlmout-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/FloatDivision.c).

Comment: Nossa, esqueci desse detalhe: parte decimal :/ e usar float ou double pra variável resultado. De qualquer forma o programa não roda corretamente. Tem como fazer funcionar só usando **if** ou **switch**?

Comment: Tive que declarar todas as variáveis como **float** e agora funcionou exceto quando o valor é exatamente 20% a mais do salário ("deveria aceitar o empréstimo, mas não está").

Comment: Está aí mostrando que funciona. Não vejo motivo pra usar `if` neste caso, menos ainda com `switch`. Como eu disse, usar `float` para valor monetário não dá certo mesmo.

Comment: Pois é, tentei fazer usando `if` porque o exercício está no capítulo do livro que ensina Comando de Controle Condicional. Enfim, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Desculpem a picuinhice desta minha resposta...

O código apresentado pelo @Maniero

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float salario; // salário
    float emprestimo; // valor empréstimo
    scanf ("%f %f", &salario, &emprestimo);
    printf("emprestimo%s concedido", emprestimo /salario <= 1.2 ? "" : " nao");
}
```

(no geral perfeito, como habitualmente) tem um problema para o 
caso limite de o rácio ser exatamente igual a 1.2, referido no comentário do PO:

> e agora funcionou exceto quando o valor é exatamente 20% a mais do salário ("deveria aceitar o empréstimo, mas não está").

```
$ cc x.c -o x
$ x
100 
120
emprestimo não concedido    --> 1.2
```

Isto resulta de o número 1.2 não ter uma representação exacta em
floats / doubles em computador: ligado à sua representação em binário
este número é uma dizima infinita periódica (se fosse 1.25 não haveria problema)

No geral comparações de reais envolvendo igualdades precisam de prever um erro...

```
#define ERRO 0.0000000001
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    float salario; // salário
    float emprestimo; // valor empréstimo
    scanf ("%f %f", &salario, &emprestimo);
    printf("emprestimo%s concedido", emprestimo /salario <= 1.2+ERRO ? "" : " nao");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem amigo, otem dois problemas aí, o primeiro é

```
if (resultado <= 1.2){
```

Isso porque se for 20 % maior que o valor do salário, ele vai imprimir, no caso você teria que usar

```
if(resultado <1.2){
```

Dessa forma enquanto o resultado for menor que 1.2 ele imprimirá "emprestimo concedido".
O segundo problema é que você usou int, dessa forma você não recebe casas decimais. Basta trocar int por float.

```
float n1; // salário
float n2; // valor empréstimo
float resultado;
scanf ("%f %f",&n1,&n2);

resultado = n2/n1;
if (resultado < 1.2){
    printf("emprestimo concedido");
}else{
    printf("emprestimo nao concedido");
}
return 0;
```

Abraços